# Violation of the C definition?

Tags: c

The C standard states that any character in the machine's standard printing set will never be negative.But the following code:

```
char c=1234;
printf("%d\t%c",c,c);
```

gives a negative output and prints a strange character,meaning that the character is in machine's printing character set.Is the C standard being violated here?

Comment: This assumption `meaning that the character is in machine's printing character set` is not true.

Comment: `Is the C standard being violated here?` No. The program is just not a valid C program.

Comment: @Loki Astari,any way to show that "my assumption that the character is in machine's printing character set" is wrong?

Comment: @LokiAstari: that's not undefined. Arguments to variadic functions get promoted before the call. Passing something larger than int would be a problem though.

Comment: @LokiAstari: this is a valid C program. It just uses "undefined behaviour", which makes it (probably) not fully portable among all existing C compiler implementations.

Comment: @user1369975: Can you give a reference where the C standard requires characters to be non-negative? I could not find it in my copy.

Comment: @DocBrown: I would argue that undefined behavior is non confirming thus not a valid program. But I am not going to argue that point too hard. As you are probably correct.

Comment: @user1369975: The fact that the program does not work as you expect shows your assumption is false. The real question is what do you think the phrase means. Then we can decide if it even applies.

Comment: @Loki: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084857/automatic-type-promotion-in-variadic-function - types with a conversion rank lower than int get promoted ("default argument promotions are performed on trailing parameters" in C11 §6.5.2.2/7)

Answer (score 2):

The part of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) (link is to a late draft of C11) you're interested in is section 6.3.1.3 (page 69 of the PDF), which says:

> **6.3  Conversions**
>
> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>   is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot
>   be represented in it; either the result is implementation-deﬁned or an
>   implementation-deﬁned signal is raised.

Your first statement requires the conversion of an `int` (signed or unsigned, doesn't matter in this case) to a `signed char`.  Because the new type is signed and can't represent `1234`, the behavior described in item 3 is triggered.

Indeed,  if you have warnings enabled on when you compile the code, you should get an error like this one from gcc:

> `junk.c:4: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion`

Comment: The `int` is `signed`. The char it is implementation defined if it is `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: @LokiAstari:  Which was exactly my point.

Answer (score 1):

> The C standard states that any character in the machine's standard printing set will never be negative.

Where? C++ has that constraint for characters **in the basic execution character set** (and not all printing characters, see 2.2/3 in C++98, 2.3/11 in C++11), but in the past I've looked for a similar clause for C and didn't found it.

Even for C++, if the character printed is a "strange character", that means it is probably not in the basic character set and thus the behavior by itself gives no hint about conformance. BTW, even if the glyph was similar to one in the basic character set, that wouldn't mean much, a 'A' for instance could be intended as an upper case alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not an expert on this, but the key is what the C standard means by "machine's **standard** printing set". On most modern machines/systems this will be 7-bit ASCII. So as long as you assign just characters of that range to a `char` variable, you can be sure that, when interpreted as an integer, you get a positive value.

The (full) printing set of a machine may contain a lot more characters, but when you, for example, assign an umlaut like ä, ö or ü to a character variable, you have to expect on some machines the integer conversion of that variable becoming <0, on others >0, this is *not* defined in the standard. Furthermore, there is no guarantee that such a character will always be printed as the same letter, this may, for example, depend on the activate codepage or the environment of the program.